# Using the random forest method for classification to train my model, tuning your model based on the validation data set.Not using cross validation

Tags: r, for-loop, random-forest

I separate my dataset into three sets. train set, validation set, and test set. I want to use random forest method to train the data. But, To find the best ntree, mytry, and nnodes I want to use a validation set and see which are the best parameters. Then, I want to use those parameters for my training set.
I do not want to use the caret package since it used cross-validation.
I am dealing with classification problem.

```
 a=as.numeric(2:15)
 for (i in 2:15){
 model2= randomForest(as.factor(V2)~ .,data = vset, ntree=500, mtry=i, importance=TRUE)
 predValid2 = predict(model2, newdata = test, type = "class")
a[i-1]= mean(predValid2 == test$V2)
}
n.tree=seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 100)
n.mtry= seq(from = 1, to = 15, by = 1)

model3= randomForest(as.factor(V2)~ .,data = vset, ntree=n.tree, mtry=n.mtry, 
importance=TRUE)
```

I use the above codes to write a loop but I believe they are not correct.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me to find the best parameters based on validation set not cross validation

Comment: I'm a little puzzled why you don't want to use cross-validation for model tuning (with the validation set). **caret** does have nice functionality for model tuning, check out the help for `caret::train` and you might find what you need. (`tuneGrid` might be the trick).  If you can post some example data it might be easier to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you don't want to use cross-validation, you can use `caret` without it. (It's not required...) `ntree`: it's unlikely to make a difference in your model. Plot the model to see where it evens out; pay attention to the y-axis, though. (If y is in the .0001 range, it's flat... regardless of the line movement.) For `mtry`, it's unpredictable. You would have to run the model repeatedly with different values. The `randomForest` function will keep your categorical data together; `caret` separates them—you have more options with `mtry` using `caret` (if you have any categorical independent var).